# Want to implement Search function in springboot restapi

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, rest

So i have two entity classes Employee and Address  and they are in @OneToOne Relation  I'm able to search a Employee's with different parameter like name,designation,department. But i want to search a employee using address fields like Areaname,pincode, phone etc.. How to implement this functionality i'm currently using  JpaRepo with Mysql.

```
@Entity
    public class Employee{
        @Id@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)    
    private int id; 
    private String Name;
    private String Designation;
    private String Department;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;}

@Entity
public class Address{
private String Streetname;
private String Areaname;    
private String City;
private Long pincode;
@Id
private Long phone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
@Query("FROM Employee AS emp LEFT JOIN emp.address AS adr WHERE adr.areaname= ?1")
public List<Employee > FindAllEmployeeByAreaName(String areaname);
```

Comment: But this would require another / mapping i'm not looking for that instead i'm looking for something dynamic /search mapping for all params be it employee or address.